# The import com.google cannot be resolved on VSCode

Tags: java, gradle, import, importerror

I have recently begun working on a project that requires me to use gson, however, when I try to import the file it says: "The import com.google cannot be resolved" I have already created my build.gradle and I beoieve I have imported it properly.

```
apply plugin: 'java'

dependencies {
  implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.10.1'
}
```

It is in the same folder as the file I'm importing gson for, I have already tried restaring VS code.

Comment: There's more than just `com.google` to importing gson, are you sure your import is right? (`import com.google.gson.Gson;`)

Comment: yes I am, I just wrote com.google in my question because that's the only part that's showing up in the error

Comment: Do you have the vscode "Gradle for Java" extension installed? Just adding a build.gradle file doesn't do anything if nothing understands that file. https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-build#_gradle a minimal build.gradle file also needs to contain `repositories { mavenCentral() }` or another repository where gradle can look for the dependencies. Would start from a template project (`gradle init` can create one if you have it installed) or use a Java IDE like IntelliJ to create the project, VSCode's Java support is IMO a bit lacking

Comment: Yes, I do have the extension, after your feedback I changed my grade, it is now this:

Comment: plugins {
    id 'java'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.9.1'
}

tasks.named('compileJava') {
    doFirst {
        options.compilerArgs += ['-Xlint:none']
    }
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

tasks.build {
    dependsOn helloWorldTask
}

}

Comment: I still get the error on my java code

Comment: can you run any of the gradle tasks like "build" from the VSCode gradle sidebar window thing?

Comment: no, I can't run the tasks